# Changing the background color of a custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've been setting the backgroundColor of buttons by doing `self.layer.backgroundColor = someColor`.

However, this doesn't seem to work with a custom class? I have this general class that I use:

```
class DarkButton: BaseButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.77, green:0.77,
                                             blue:0.77, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.clipsToBounds = false
    }

}
```

the self.layer.backgroundColor works just fine. Now if I extend it, like so:

```
class SuperCoolButton: DarkButton {

    required init() {
        super.init()
        self.setUp()
    }

    required init(spacing: Spacing) {
        super.init(spacing: spacing)
        self.setUp()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setUp()
    }

    func setUp() {
        self.generateImage()
        self.changeBGColor()
    }

    func generateImage() {
        let image = UIImage(named: "logoSmall") as UIImage?
        self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)
        self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }

    func changeBGColor() {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }

}
```

the backgroundColor stays that of the DarkButton backgroundColor, however setting the image does indeed work >_>

Comment: Why are you setting the background color of a layer? Since a `UIButton` has a `backgroundColor` property of it's own, all subclasses should too. Or is the issue that `SuperCoolButton` is a subclass of `DarkButton`, which is a subclass of `BaseButton`.... which you've shown no code for?

Comment: why don't you use `self.backgroundColor` instead of self.layer.backgroundColor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `layoutSubviews()` implemented in the super class(DarkButton) gets called after `setUp` method of `DarkButton`. You need to override layoutSubviews in your class `SuperCoolButton` and call setUp there instead of at its init method.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setUp()
}
```

**EDIT**:
I think you should move the code which you have written inside `[layoutSubviews][1]` of `DarkButton` class.

`layoutSubviews` method gets called multiple times and only the code related to the layout of the view should be there.

> Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise
>   layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the
>   autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not
>   offer the behavior you want.

The ideal place to change layer's corner radius and setTitleColor or background color is either at init of the custom view or at `awakeFromNib`:(only, if the view is always going to be designed in nib).

Because you want to change the backgroud color of button at some later time. You can simply call your changeBgColor method on `SuperCoolButton`. Earlier it was not working, because `layoutSubviews` must be setting the background color back to the default.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Two quick questions 1) what should go in the init, in general? 2) If I wanted to change the backgroundColor at a later time, e.g. the button should glow after 5 minutes pass, would I be able to call btn.changeBGColor(color: UIColor.green.cgColor)? It seems not to be working either

Comment: e.g. I tried setting in the UIVIewController that the button is in, on viewDidAppear, instantiatedCoolButton.changeBGColor(color: UIColor.purple.cgColor) and it didn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: The reason being that you are changing the background color inside layoutSubviews. This is not the ideal place to put such methods. Only the layout related stuff should be there as this method gets called multiple times. You should move the background color change code from layoutsubviews and call it inside init or from awakeFromNib.

Comment: Infact, the other stuff related to layer's corner radius and change of title color should also be moved from your superclass's layoutSubviews method. Let me edit the answer to include this info as well.

Comment: thanks. I don't exactly follow on how I can change the backgroundColor of the button at a later time yet though. e.g. say I have a function called invertViewController() that goes through every single item, and changes the colors, if I were to do this with the button and call changeBGColor, it doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: @VDog: Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks, I got it working! I guess the real question I have is, overriding layoutSubviews and putting things in there makes them permanent and immutable, whereas things in the init can be changed?

Comment: @VDog: No, its more like, because layoutSubviews gets called multiple times at diferent points, its not an ideal place to place something which you do not want to get called mutiple times. init of a method gets called once at initialization time and hence all the default beahviour logic should be there. If you want teh appearance to change at later stage, you have correctly exposed a method(changeBGColor) that does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

Do not call your `setUp()` method in `init` instead of this call it in `layoutSubviews`

```
class SuperCoolButton: DarkButton {

    required init() {
        super.init()
        //self.setUp()
    }

    required init(spacing: Spacing) {
        super.init(spacing: spacing)
        //self.setUp()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //self.setUp()
    }

    func setUp() {
        self.generateImage()
        self.changeBGColor()
    }

    func generateImage() {
        let image = UIImage(named: "logoSmall") as UIImage?
        self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)
        self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }

    func changeBGColor() {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setUp()
    }
}
```